# How do I implement custom integral transform with kernel $\cos^2 (zx)$ or $|\cos (zx)|$ in Mathematica?

Tags: integral-transforms

I want a transform similar to Fourier transform but with a different kernel. With infinite limits:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \cos^2(zx)dx$$

I want it to work with distributions and other things, similar to Fourier transform.

Comment: ...and the limits? Why not write down the explicit definition of what you want to work with?

Comment: @ J. M. added...

Answer (score 3):

Since $\cos^2(t)=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\cos(2t)$ you have
$$
F\{f\}(z)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \cos^2(zx)dx=
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\cos(2zx)\right)dx
$$
So you can use `FourierCosTransform` as

```
F[f_] := (Integrate[f[x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}] + 
    Sqrt[Pi/2]FourierCosTransform[(f[x]+f[-x])/2, x, 2 z])/2
```

Explanation: `FourierCosTransform`'s limits are from 0 to $\infty$ so to identify with your integral I apply it to the even part (thanks for J.M. for the comment). There's also a factor of $\sqrt{2/\pi}$ that needs to be removed (you can also do it using `FourierParameters`, but this way is more straightforward).

**EDIT**

More generally, if $\hat f$ is the standard Fourier Transform of $f$, then using the identity $\cos^2(t)=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\cos(2t)$ it is clear that
$$F{f}(z)=\frac{1}{2}\hat f(0)+\frac{1}{2}\Re\left[\hat f(2z)\right]$$
If your function $f$ is not square-integrable (such as $\cos^2x$ or $x$ as you tried in the comments), i.e. it has a delta singularity at $z=0$ then the 
term $\hat f(0)$ will give you $\delta(0)$ which is infinite. It is not defined in the distribution sense.

Implementing the transform in this way is:

```
F[f_] := Block[{fh},
  fh = FourierTransform[f, x, z];
  (fh /. z -> 0)/2 + Re[(fh /. z -> 2 z)]/2
  ]
```

Indeed, `F[Cos[x]^2]` returns what you expect, with a `DiracDelta[0]` term.

Comment: Per the docs, `FourierCosTransform[]`'s limits are from $0$ to $\infty$. So, you need to apply the transform to the even part, $\frac{f(x)+f(-x)}{2}$.

Comment: @J.M. Thanks, fixed.

Comment: Does not work for me: I am trying to apply it to Function[x,Cos[x]^2] and it does not return what expected.

Comment: The same is with function f[x]=Function[x,x]

Comment: Both the functions you wrote are not in $L^2$ and their integral does not converge. For square-integrable functions it works perfectly for me

Comment: But Fourier transform works even when Riemann integral does not converge. I want this also to work this way. Otherwise I could just express it as in the question.

Comment: Should not it give Delta function when applied to Cos[x]^2?

Comment: @Anixx No. It should give infinity. I explain it in the revised answer.

Comment: Perhaps `CosSquaredTransform[f_,x_,z_] := With[{ft=Sqrt[Pi/2]FourierTransform[f,x,2z]}, (ft/.z->0) + ComplexExpand @ Re[ft]]` to fix fourier parameter differences and eliminate Re?